# R: How to work with time series of sub-hour data?

Tags: r, time, statistics, time-series, series

i just started with R and finished some tutorials. However, i am trying to get into time series analysis and got big troubles with it. I made a data frame that looks like that:

```
    Date        Time        T1
 1  2014-05-22  15:15:00    21.6
 2  2014-05-22  15:20:00    21.2
 3  2014-05-22  15:25:00    21.3
 4  2014-05-22  15:30:00    21.5
 5  2014-05-22  15:35:00    21.1
 6  2014-05-22  15:40:00    21.5
```

Since i didn't want to work with half days, i removed the first and last day from the data frame. Since R didnt recognize the date nor time as such, but as "factor", i used the lubridate library to change it properly. Now it looks like that:

```
    Date        Time    T1
1   2014-05-23      0S  14.2
2   2014-05-23  5M 0S   14.1
3   2014-05-23  10M 0S  14.6
4   2014-05-23  15M 0S  14.3
5   2014-05-23  20M 0S  14.4
6   2014-05-23  25M 0S  14.5
```

Now the trouble really starts. Using ts function changes date to 16944 and time to 0. How do i setup a data frame with the correct start date and frequency? A new set of data comes in everty 5 min so frequency should be 288. I also tried to set the start date as a vector. Since 22th of may was the 142th day of the year i tried this

```
ts_df <- ts(df, start=c(2014, 142/365), frequency=288)
```

No error there, but when i go for `start(ds_df)` i get  and `end(ds_df)`:

```
[1] 2013.998
[1] 2058.994
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to work with these kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"ts"` class is typically not a good fit for that type of data.  Assuming `DF` is the data frame shown reproducibly in the Note at the end of this answer we convert it to a `"zoo"` class object and then perform some manipulations.  The related xts package could also be used.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 1:2, tz = "")

window(z, start = "2014-05-22 15:25:00")

head(z, 3) # first 3
head(z, -3) # all but last 3
tail(z, 3) # last 3
tail(z, -3) # all but first 3

z[2:4] # 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of z

coredata(z) # numeric vector of data values
time(z) # vector of datetimes

fortify.zoo(z) # data frame whose 2 cols are (1) datetimes and (2) data values

aggregate(z, as.Date, mean) # convert to daily averaging values

ym <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, mean) # convert to monthly averaging values
frequency(ym) <- 12 # only needed since ym only has length 1
as.ts(ym) # year/month series can be reasonably converted to ts

plot(z)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z)
```

`read.zoo` could also have been used to read the data in from a file.

**Note:** `DF` used above in reproducible form:

```
DF <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2014-05-22", 
class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("15:15:00", "15:20:00", 
    "15:25:00", "15:30:00", "15:35:00", "15:40:00"), class = "factor"), 
    T1 = c(21.6, 21.2, 21.3, 21.5, 21.1, 21.5)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Time", "T1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Hi Grothendieck, thank you for your quick reply. It took me awhile to reply again, but you helped alot.